# MVC4 How to load Jquery files in areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, area

I have trouble using Jquery timeago in an area.
To understand better my issue here are the steps I followed:

- I have a simple index page using Jquery timeago that works perfectely on  my website.
- For some reasons I need to have it in an area. So I created the area with my controller and a simple page. Page is displayed properly, so area was created properly
- I make a copy/paste of my "old" page to my "area" page. This time I have the following error:
- ".../Scripts/jquery.timeago.js"
- 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Note that the file is loaded in a bundle loaded in the Application_Start method of the Global.asax

If anybody has an idea, it would help me a lot!

Comment: This is going to be fairly hard to trouble-shoot without seeing your view's markup.

Comment: But what is the difference using javascript files in areas? should I make a folder in the area and make a copy of the file there as well?

Comment: Like I said, hard to offer anything useful without seeing what you're doing. That being said, one problem you can run into is not setting the path to the script file(s) properly. Make sure you use a virtual path like ~/scripts/jquery.min.js - the view engine in MVC4 will automatically rewrite it to the correct relative path.